# Como instalar o pacote ajdamico?

Tags: r

Eu tentei, mas:

```
Downloading GitHub repo ajdamico/lodown@master
from URL [...]  
Installing lodown  
Downloading GitHub repo jimhester/archive@master
from URL [...]  
trying URL [...]  
Error in utils: download.file: cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools34.exe'

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.
Please download and install Rtools 3.4 from [...]  
Installation failed: Could not find build tools necessary to build archive  
ERROR: dependency 'archive' is not available for package 'lodown'  
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/lodown'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Este erro está acontecendo porque você necessita de ter instalado `Rtools` para compilar packages `R`.

Você pode baixar o instalador `Rtools 3.4` no site [r-project.org](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)